# Does anyone have a group? or Who has a group? or Who already have a group?

Tags: sentence-choice

If I want to ask to my classmates about they already have some group to do a homework, it is correct to say: Does anyone have a group? or Who has a group? or Who already have a group?

Comment: There are lots of ways to ask this but here are some simple ways: Is anyone in a group? Who is in a group? ....you would need to fill out these phrases with your own ideas.

Comment: You right, thank u Bruce. But I have a doubt, are these questions grammatically correct?